# npm && not working to run two tasks

Tags: npm

I'm trying to use straight up npm as my build tool.

```
    {
      "name": "ang-starter",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "jshintConfig": {
        "predef": ["angular"]
      },
      "scripts": {
        "autoprefixer": "postcss -u autoprefixer -r src/assets/css/*",
        "scss": "node-sass --output-style compressed -o src/assets/css src/assets/sass/main.scss",
        "jshint": "jshint src/app/*.js",
        "uglify": "uglifyjs src/app/*.js -o src/assets/js/app.min.js",
        "serve": "browser-sync start --server --files 'src/assets/css/, src/assets/js/*.js, **/*.html, !node_modules/**/*.html'",
        "watch:css": "onchange 'src/assets/sass/*.scss' -- npm run scss",
        "watch:js": "onchange 'src/app/**/*.js' -- npm run jshint && npm run uglify",
        "watch:all": "npm-run-all -p serve watch:css watch:js watch:images",
        "postinstall": "npm run build:all && npm run watch:all"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^6.3.7",
        "browser-sync": "^2.13.0",
        "jshint": "^2.9.2",
        "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
        "npm-run-all": "^2.3.0",
        "onchange": "^2.5.0",
        "postcss-cli": "^2.5.2",
        "uglify-js": "^2.6.4"
      }
    }
```

My folder set up is like.

```
    src
        app
            controllers
            directives
            filters
            services
        assets
            css
            images
            js
            sass
        templates

    index.html

    package.json
```

My problem is with watch:js, I can run jshint and uglify separately and they work but if I run watch:js which uses && to run jshint and then uglify then the uglify doesn't work and it stops at jshint.

Comment: same issue here ... could you solve it in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

Try `npm run watch:js` instead of `npm watch:js`.

I had the same issue with npm in angular2. The build-script:

```
"build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail"
```

wouldn't work - but both commands were running standalone. The `run` solved it for me.

Comment: `test`and `start` are special values and can be invoked directly. for the rest you have to use `run`